# Pandas how to replace int64 null marker -999999 with <NA> without casting to float?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, casting

I have integer columns that have a lot of None.
So I try to

```
>>> int64_nan = pd.Series([None], dtype="Int64")[0]
>>> to_num_int = partial(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce', downcast='signed')
>>> df[int_cols[:5]].fillna(-99999).apply(to_num_int).astype('int64')
      SEQ  TRAN_CODE_N  USAGE_CODE_1_N   PART_NUM  VAL_2
0       1          366               1     -99999 -99999
1       2          366               1     -99999 -99999
2       3          366               1     -99999 -99999
3       4          366               1     -99999 -99999
4       5          366               1     -99999 -99999
...   ...          ...             ...        ...    ...
1437    4          387          -99999  886383232 -99999
1438    1          385          -99999  972651520 -99999
1439    1          385          -99999     -99999 -99999
1440    1          385          -99999  968259328 -99999
1441    2          385          -99999  968259328 -99999

[1442 rows x 5 columns]
>>> df[int_cols[:5]].fillna(-99999).apply(to_num_int).astype('int64').dtypes
SEQ               int64
TRAN_CODE_N       int64
USAGE_CODE_1_N    int64
PART_NUM          int64
VAL_2             int64
dtype: object
```

which seems like a perfect solution
except when I attempt to replace the markers -99999

I get floats back!

```
>>> df[int_cols[:5]].fillna(-99999).apply(to_num_int).astype('int64').replace(-99999, int64_nan)
      SEQ  TRAN_CODE_N  USAGE_CODE_1_N     PART_NUM  VAL_2
0       1        366.0             1.0          NaN    NaN
1       2        366.0             1.0          NaN    NaN
2       3        366.0             1.0          NaN    NaN
3       4        366.0             1.0          NaN    NaN
4       5        366.0             1.0          NaN    NaN
...   ...          ...             ...          ...    ...
1437    4        387.0             NaN  886383232.0    NaN
1438    1        385.0             NaN  972651520.0    NaN
1439    1        385.0             NaN          NaN    NaN
1440    1        385.0             NaN  968259328.0    NaN
1441    2        385.0             NaN  968259328.0    NaN

[1442 rows x 5 columns]
>>> df[int_cols[:5]].fillna(-99999).apply(to_num_int).astype('int64').replace(-99999, int64_nan).dtypes
SEQ                 int64
TRAN_CODE_N       float64
USAGE_CODE_1_N    float64
PART_NUM          float64
VAL_2             float64
dtype: object
```

Is this a bug? Is there a way to avoid this?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The solution was simple as:

```
df[int_cols] = df[int_cols].fillna(-99999).apply(
       to_num_int).astype(pd.Int64Dtype(),
                          errors='ignore').replace(-99999, int64_nan)
```

Very convoluted but works.